# CSS overlay on images

Tags: html, css

I want to simply overlay these 4 images with a block of colour, and text aligned in the middle of each. But with my current use of "position: absolute" to get each image in the correct position and z-index etc. I'm finding it hard to attempt something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jimjeffers/mG78d/1/ and get it to work. My position absolute seems to always break other code I've been trying from stackoverflow and others, even tried a few jquery scripts.

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1k7RgDS

HTML

```
<div class="index-gallery">
            <img src="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>/Images/1.JPG" alt="" class="img1" />
            <img src="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>/Images/2.JPG" alt="" class="img2" />
            <!-- <img src="<?php //HTTP_HOST ?>/Images/3.JPG" alt="" class="img3" /> -->
            <img src="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>/Images/6.JPG" alt="" class="img3" />
            <img src="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>/Images/5.JPG" alt="" class="img4" />
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#index-gallery .index-gallery { margin-bottom: 30px; }
#index-gallery .index-gallery img:hover { opacity:0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */ }
#index-gallery .index-gallery img:before { content: "Show Home Hemel Hempstead"; }
#index-gallery .index-gallery .img1 { width: 550px; top: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 3; display: block; }
#index-gallery .index-gallery .img2 { width: 550px; right: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 2; display: block; }
#index-gallery .index-gallery .img3 { width: 400px; top: 400px; left: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 4; display: block; }
#index-gallery .index-gallery .img4 { width: 710px; top: 400px; right: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 1; display: block; }
```

I've got a little bit of a transparency code to work but looking more for what's on that JSFIDDLE with the ability to center the text in the middle when hovered over with colour overlay. If you have a suggestion which would change all the code I don't mind, if this is bad practice what i've got so far.

Comment: You would have to wrap **each** image in an element with `position:relative` and work from there. To be honest, positioning each image like that is not an optimal layout method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - Working with what you already have you could just try this route.  Minimal position changes and I've added Paragraph tags inside your spans so you can position the text absolutely.

http://jsfiddle.net/9H7eM/

```
<span><p>Hello</p></span>

#overlay {position: relative;}

#overlay span {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#overlay span p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    top: 30px;
    font: bold 16px arial;
}
```

IF you're open to changing your code, you could try an approach similar to this: **http://jsfiddle.net/te6t8/1/**

But if you're already happy with how it is, stick with what you have and know!

Comment: Would it be possible to only show the Span text on hover with the colour change.

Comment: Sure - I've updated the span styles so it affects all spans and I've updated the P tag and hover state at the bottom of the style so it only displays when the div has been hovered over. ------ 

     
The main issue with including the P inside the span is that it'll change the opacity of the text as well as the background.------ 

     
Here's the new fiddle - **http://jsfiddle.net/te6t8/2/**------ 


   - Is that okay?